# Child object properties are NULL, after parent update in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Have following hibernate POJOs

```
@Entity
Class Parent {
  long id // id, generate auto increment
  Child child // many to one, eager fetch, no cascade
}

@Entity
Class Child{
  long id // id, generate auto increment
  String name;
}
```

Have following spring service

```
@Transactional
void myMethod() {
 Parent parent = session.getParent(id); // id=10
 // Here parent has child object {id: 20, name: "FirstChild"}

 Child newChild = new Child(21); //DB has a child row with id 21 and name "SecondChild"
 parent.setChild (newChild);

 session.update(parent);

 System.out.println(parent.getChild.getName())
 // This print NULL
}
```

I expected this will print "SecondChild", as parent is a persistent object and we are in same hibernate session. Where I'm wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Parent parent = session.getParent(id); // id=10
 // Here parent has child object {id: 20, name: "FirstChild"}

 Child newChild = session.getChild(21); 
 parent.setChild(newChild);

 session.update(parent);
```

Retrieve the child from DB rather than creating it manually.